# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The error comes after the word init: before the function. I'm newer to coding and not sure what the problem is. This is jquery.

```
init: function (options) {
        var self = this, o = this.options, c = o.classes, d = $(document), i;
        // Set up the cart configuration.
        $.extend(true, o, options);
        // Set up the storage method.
        this.saveCart = this.setStorageMethod(o.storage);
        if (this.saveCart) {
            this.webstore();
            // Get the shopping cart.
            o.properties = $.merge([ c.id, c.stock, c.price, c.quantity, o.title ], o.properties);
            this.saveCart(true);
            if (this.cart.timeout === null) {
                this.cart.timeout = this.timeout(true);
            }

            // Build the shopping cart.
            $.each(this.carts, function (cart) {
                d.delegate(cart + ' .' + c.remove, 'click', 'remove', $.proxy(self.listen, self));
                d.delegate(cart + ' :input', 'change', 'cart-options', $.proxy(self.listen, self));
                self.buildCart(cart);
            });
            // Update total amounts.
            this.updateTotals();
            o.ready.call(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `init: function(` would need to be attached to an object literal,.. But if you just want a function init, just do `function init (options) {`

Comment: @Keith somehow init got before the word function instead of after, guess I needed someone to tell me that lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function named 'init' Just put it after function like so:

```
function init(options) { }
```

Unless you're wanting to create your own jQuery function via prototyping:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    init: function(options){}
})
```

Read more on the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/